# Show div based on selection & hide previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how it was possible to show a DIV by clicking on another DIV and then hiding a different DIV that was active before.

I was messing around with the JQuery slideUp() and slideDown(); and I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the JSFiddle I'm working with to just mess around:
https://jsfiddle.net/wLayxqq2/

I'm trying to show the content related to those color!

I have found similar JSFiddle that show how to hide and show content from ONE div but not how to hide the content from the previous "active" div!

Code HTML:

```
<div class="option">Red</div>
<div class="option">Yellow</div>
<div class="option">Green</div>

<div id="red" class="colors"> This is content for red </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors"> This is content for Yellow </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors"> This is content for Green </div>
```

Code CSS:

```
.option{
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 1px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: wheres the code you have messed around with ? i.e javascript

Comment: It is not really clear what you want. 
Correct me if i'm mistaking: 
Clicking on a div must cause to show up another div and hide the previous one?

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLayxqq2/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Give a data-attribute to the divs and map with colors, the you can use like

```
<div data-id="red" class="option">Red</div>
<div data-id="yellow" class="option">Yellow</div>
<div data-id="blue" class="option">Green</div>

<div id="red" class="colors"> This is content for red </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors"> This is content for Yellow </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors"> This is content for Green </div>
```

jquery

```
$(".colors").hide();
$(".option").click(function(){
    $(".colors").hide();
    $("#"+$(this).data("id")).show();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wLayxqq2/8/)

Comment: +1 for this solution also as it will probably be the solution to use on production code because the OP's example is most probably just a simplified example and you probably can't rely on content of the div to trigger the event...

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(".colors").hide();
$('.option').click(function(){
    $(".colors").hide();
  $("#"+$(this).text().toLowerCase()).show();

});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wLayxqq2/10/)**

Comment: You might want to add `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` calls so that you don't have to care about your id's/text case, but +1 for the straightforward answer.

Comment: OP has a mistake: `<div class="option">Green</div>` but `<div id="blue" class="colors">`. This solution won't work in this case.

Comment: Note that this works with OP's example, therefore the +1, but this will most probably be inappropriate in a real-life situation where the content of divs to be clicked will probably be longer/different from the target id

Answer (score 0):

HTML:
    Red
    Yellow
    Green

```
<div id="red" class="colors"> This is content for red </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors"> This is content for Yellow </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors"> This is content for Green </div>
```

JS:

```
$('.option').click(function(){
    $('.colors').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data('id')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small mistake:

```
<div class="option">Green</div>
...
<div id="blue" class="colors"> This is content for Green </div>
```

So using the name in the DIV to show the content may fail you.

Instead, you can include some unique identifying information in the divs you want to click. You can use jQuery's [data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method.

```js
$(".option").on("click", function(e){
    var id = $(this).data("color");
    $(".colors").hide();  // Hide all content DIVs
    $("#"+id).show();     // Show the target DIV
})
```

```css
.option{
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 1px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}
.colors {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option" data-color="red">Red</div>
<div class="option" data-color="yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="option" data-color="green">Green</div>

<div id="red" class="colors"> This is content for red </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors"> This is content for Yellow </div>
<div id="green" class="colors"> This is content for Green </div>
```

#### Your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrL9mebw/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="option" data-color="red">Red</div>
<div class="option"  data-color="yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="option"  data-color="green">Green</div>

<div id="red" class="colors"> This is content for red </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors"> This is content for Yellow </div>
<div id="green" class="colors"> This is content for Green </div>

$(".option").on("click",function(){
    color = $(this).data("color");
    $(".colors").slideUp();
    $("#"+color).slideDown();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4q38yo4z/