# How to make only one div visible at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've 3 button and each has its own box and and these boxes are hidden and when I press the button one I want the box one to open and when I press the button two the the box one should automatically get closed and show the box two.

but what I've here is which I press the button1 and the button 2 then both the boes are being displayed.

Hope you understood my question

My code is as below

```js
<!--JQuery-->
    $('.btn1').click(function(){
      $('.img1').toggle()
    });

    $('.btn2').click(function(){
      $('.img2').toggle()
    });

    $('.btn3').click(function(){
      $('.img3').toggle()
    });
```

```css
<!--CSS-->
    .btn1, .btn2, .btn3 {
     border:4px solid;
     float:left;
     margin-right: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     width: 100px;
     text-align:center;
    }

    .img1, .img2, .img3 {
     border:1px solid;
     float:left;
     margin-right: 10px;
     display:none;
     width: 100px;
     text-align:center;
    }
    .div {
     clear:both;
    }
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
    <div class="btn1">Button Image</div>
    <div class="btn2">Button Audio</div>
    <div class="btn3">Button Video</div>
    <div class="div"></div>

    <div class="img1">Image 1</div>
    <div class="img2">Image 2</div>
    <div class="img3">Image 3</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639228/show-div-based-on-selection-hide-previous-div

Comment: the basic pattern for this kind of task is, when clicking any button : 1) Hide all items that may be visible 2) show the exact one you want to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of custom `data-*` attributes to target the corresponding element. First, hide them **all**, then **show** the target

```js
$('[class^="btn"]').click(function(){
  $('[class^="img"]').hide();
  var target = $(this).attr('data-target')
  $(target).show();
});

$('.cancel').click(function(){
  $('[class^="img"]').hide();
 
});
```

```css
.btn1, .btn2, .btn3, .cancel {
 border:4px solid;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 100px;
 text-align:center;
}

.img1, .img2, .img3 {
 border:1px solid;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 display:none;
 width: 100px;
 text-align:center;
}
.div {
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn1" data-target=".img1">Button Image</div>
<div class="btn2" data-target=".img2">Button Audio</div>
<div class="btn3" data-target=".img3">Button Video</div>
<div class="cancel">Cancel</div>

<div class="img1">Image 1</div>
<div class="img2">Image 2</div>
<div class="img3">Image 3</div>
```

Comment: GREAT :)
This is what I wanted :0

Comment: I need a cancel button in the image div which can close the image box but then again if we click the image button the again it show show the image box. 
Can you do that for me pls??

Comment: @Mohamed, see my updated answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Great piece of Work dude :)

Comment: Bro. Want to talk to you can you give ur social media id??

Comment: If this is not the proper way of asking then pls be kind enough to forgive me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the logic here by grouping the HTML elements by class and using a single event handler. You can then relate the `button` to its `div` by `index`. Try this:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.img').hide().eq($(this).index()-1).show();
});
```

```css
.btn {
    border: 4px solid;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 20px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.img {
    border:1px solid;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.div {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">Button Image</div>
<div class="btn">Button Audio</div>
<div class="btn">Button Video</div>
<div class="div"></div>

<div class="img">Image 1</div>
<div class="img">Image 2</div>
<div class="img">Image 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var showImg = function(element){
  var showElement = element.attr("data-show");
  $("." + showElement).toggle();
}

$(".btn").click(function(){
  $(".img").hide();
  showImg($(this));
});
```

```css
.btn1, .btn2, .btn3 {
 border:4px solid;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 100px;
 text-align:center;
 cursor : pointer;
}

.img1, .img2, .img3 {
 border:1px solid;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 display:none;
 width: 100px;
 text-align:center;
}
.div {
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn btn1" data-show="img1">Button Image</div>
<div class="btn btn2" data-show="img2">Button Audio</div>
<div class="btn btn3" data-show="img3">Button Video</div>
<div class="div"></div>

<div class="img img1">Image 1</div>
<div class="img img2">Image 2</div>
<div class="img img3">Image 3</div>
```

Here is the working code. Hope you can understand this.

Comment: I need a cancel button in the image div which can close the image box but then again if we click the image button the again it show show the image box. Can you do that for me pls??

Comment: I think you can use the similar logic to hide the image div. Its better to do some experiments rather getting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use start with selector

```
$('[class^=btn]').click(function(){
  $('[class^=img]').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();

});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wLayxqq2/12/)**

Comment: Why not select element directly by class? `$('.btn')` instead of `$('[class=^btn]')` ? What if element class not starts with desired class? What if element class is like `mybtn`?

Comment: This should be the answer as it covers all the aspects of OP's question.   [+1]

Comment: @Justinas did you see his posted code , he does not have any '.btn' class ,and also  he mentioned btn1,btn2,btn3,there is no mybtn  there

Comment: @Bala Than think about possible bugs in future code. On change should not break every function, that is nor related to changes...

Comment: @Justinas  ya ,that i understand, Rory McCrossan posted same as you expected , that s y i moved to another possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-*` attribute to store reference (id in this case) to other element. And on click hide all certain classes, than show only clicked one reference:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.img').hide();
    $($(this).data('id')).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" data-id="#img1">Btn 1</div>
<div class="btn" data-id="#img2">Btn 2</div>
<div class="btn" data-id="#img3">Btn 3</div>

<div class="img" id="img1">Image 1</div>
<div class="img" id="img2">Image 2</div>
<div class="img" id="img3">Image 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      $('.btn1').click(function () {
         $('.img1').toggle()
         $('.img3').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
         $('.img2').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();

     });

     $('.btn2').click(function () {
         $('.img2').toggle()
         $('.img1').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
         $('.img3').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();


     });

     $('.btn3').click(function () {
         $('.img3').toggle()
         $('.img1').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
         $('.img2').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();

     });
```